# How to use the JqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a simple table, how do I use JqGrid for it? I downloaded the plugin, but don't know how to use it.

```
<table id="table-to-grid">
<tr>
            <td>something</td>
            <td>something else</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: First of all you should read the documentation, at least the [My First Grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file) part of it.

Comment: I'm trying to use the table to grid with this function:   $(function () {
    tableToGrid("#table-to-grid", {});
});

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I didn't include  headings and tbody>. It works now.

```
<table id="table-to-grid">
<tr>
<th>Heading 1</th>
<th>Heading 2</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
            <td>something</td>
            <td>something else</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to use `tableToGrid`. You should better use grid with `datatype: "local", data: mydata` options where `mydata` represents the input data. You have to specify `colModel` which describe the columns of the grid (name, sort type, format etc). It's important to divide pure data which need be placed in the grid from the presentation of the data. For example you can display boolean data as checkboxes. You need just add `formatter: "checkbox"` property in the definition of the corresponding column.